# Creating LinearLayout by the click on Button

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, programmatically-created

So, I want to add(create) LinearLayout in working application by the click on button. And I almost do this, something add(free space), but I don't see anything.

To check, if layout were added, I put TextView in it.

**my_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_for_sides"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_side_size_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 side size:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inp_side_width_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="cm"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inp_side_height_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="cm"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_side"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add side" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_calc_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Enter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btn_add_side;
    LinearLayout layout_for_sides;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout_for_sides = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_for_sides);

        btn_add_side = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_side);

        btn_add_side.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_add_side:
            LinearLayout newlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            newlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            newlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1)); 

            newlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //IT DOESN'T WORK, THERE IS NOTHING WITH BLACK BACKGROUND

            layout_for_sides.addView(newlayout);

            LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("TextView");
                    tv.setId(5);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    this.newlayout.addView(tv, lpView); //IT WORKS, I SEE FREE SPACE, BUT NEITHER TEXT

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

**Question is(Solved):** *why I don't see anything? Only free space appears, but no TextVeiw.*

**Update:** *New question: Problem was in layout_for_sides that has another LinearLayout.
I removed everything from layout_for_sides and it works.
But, I don't understand how this another layer prevents to show my newlayout?*

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, maybe unclear. I have just added question in post.

Comment: set the height of "layout_for_sides" to match_parent

Comment: TheOnlyJakobob, No, I have another layout below layout_for_sides. If I do this, I don't see it. Anyway, when I click Button, space in layout_for_sides becomes higher, so, I think, I don't need to set match_parent to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in wrong parameters of parent LinearLayout - layout_for_sides.

It has android:orientation="horizontal", but needs android:orientation="vertical".
Because of that I haven't seen anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_add_side:
            LinearLayout newlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            newlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            newlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1)); 

           //<---------------------Try this-------------------->
            layout_for_sides.addView(newlayout,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   this.newlayout.addView(tv, lpView); //IT WORKS, I SEE FREE SPACE, BUT NEITHER TEXT
                    tv.setText("TextView");
                    tv.setId(5);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

  newlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //IT DOESN'T WORK, THERE IS NOTHING WITH BLACK BACKGROUND

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I understand the idea - add View right after it was created, before adding Params. And backcolor... When I try to "layout_for_sides.addView(tv);" TextView also doesn't appears.

Comment: vipul mittal, I copied and paste all code, but nothing changed. P.S. without newlayout.setLayoutParams